# Use a single query to find all Details records if one is updated?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2017. There are two tables: Master table and Details table. If a record in the Details table is updated today, then all records in the Details table associated with the same master record in the Master table as the updated details record should be found, together with some info from the Master table. This is an example:

Master table

```
id     name
----------------
1      master1
2      master2
```

Details table

```
id  master_id   info       update_date
-----------------------------------
1   1           details1   2021-09-07
2   1           details2   2021-09-01
3   2           details2   2021-09-03
```

Suppose that today is 2021-09-07. Then the needed query should return

```
1          1        master1    details1   2021-09-07
1          2        master1    details2   2021-09-01
```

The first two columns are the ids for Master and Details records.

I am able to use a query to find the Details records that are updated today through a simple join with a condition on the update_date field. I am unable to use a **SINGLE** query to find other Details records (if any), at the same time, associated with the same Master record as an updated Details record is.

It is possible that two ore more Details records associated with the same Master record are updated today, then the results should not contain duplicate entries. For example, if #2 Details record is updated today as shown below:

```
id  master_id   info       update_date
-----------------------------------
1   1           details1   2021-09-07
2   1           details2   2021-09-07
3   2           details2   2021-09-03
```

Then the results should be:

```
1       1      master1    details1   2021-09-07
1       2      master1    details2   2021-09-07
```

How to use a single query to return the needed results?

Comment: Concerning the bottom of your question, just do a DISTINCT on the master_id, info and update_date, dont include the id? bit confused if there are other question so add a question mark after the questions you are asking to help me out

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I need ids for the Master records and Details records in results. For simplicity, I didn't add it. Now I updated the post.

Comment: Like @Andrew , I don't see a question here. What are you asking here?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Thought the title and the details of the post indicated the need. Just added the question.

Comment: Is it possible that the datatype of update_date is datetime and not date?

Comment: Thanks, @SMor!  Your input in all answers shows that you a SQL expert. Repped all your comments. The datatype is just a condition and shouldn't affect how the solution works in principle. I already selected the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a subquery to find the master_id values you need.

```
          SELECT DISTINCT master_id
            FROM details
           WHERE update_date = <<the desired date>>
```

Then we can use that in a query to obtain your result set.

```
SELECT details.id, details.master_id, 
       master.name, details.info, details.update_date
  FROM master
  JOIN details ON master.id = details.master_id
 WHERE master.id IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT master_id
            FROM details
           WHERE update_date = <<the desired date>>
   )
```

SQL is all about sets of records. So the subquery gets the set of master_id values you need for the date you need, then uses that set to get the detail records you need.

Comment: You don't need distinct in the subquery.

Comment: Tested it and the solution addresses all I need. distinct doesn't seem needed based on tests. Thanks!!!

Comment: I agree DISTINCT isn't necessary. But it doesn't cost anything. The query planner knows it needs distinct values for the IN operation. And, in my opinion (which may be worth nothing) it's a little clearer about the intent of the query. I've spent a good chunk of my life trying to figure out the intent of legacy queries, so the clearer the better.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the query you are looking for is

```
select 
     D.master_id, D.id, M.name, D.info, D.update_date         
from Details D
  inner join Master M 
     on M.id =D.master_id
 and D.master_id in 
(
select 
distinct master_id   
from Details
where 
update_date = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
)
```

Comment: You don't need distinct in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MT.* FROM masterTable MT WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM detailsTable DT WHERE MT.id = DT.master_id AND update_date = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()));
```

Comment: You don't need TOP in an EXISTS clause - does nothing useful since the engine is sufficiently intelligent to stop searching when the first row is found.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.